# Action Script 3.0 substring, slice, split, substr

Tags: apache-flex, split, substring, slice, substr

i want to get the value in between - and - how?

**Private var Test:String = "1-ALOW-The One Who Loves You Now";**

Output should be = ALOW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test = test.split("-")[1];

trace(test) // output: ALOW
```

Comment: Excellent its working!!! suppose if i want get "ALOW" in between _and- what should i do? 1_ALOW-The One Who Loves You Now

Comment: The split command splits the string to an Array according to the matching pattern. So with split("-") you get 0 = 1, 1 = ALOW, 2 = The One Who Loves You Now. So when you how that you have _ and - you could split it twice. first test = test.split("_")[1] which makes test to "ALOW-The One Who Loves You Now". Then you split the test again with - , test = test.split("-")[0], which gives you ALOW while [1] would be The One Who Loves You Now

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
Private var test:String = "1-ALOW-The One Who Loves You Now";
var my_array:Array = test.split("-");
test = my_array[0]+"_"+my_array[1]+"-"+my_array[2];
```

using [`split`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29) you get the string splitted on "-" into an array; then and concatenate the single parts in the final variable